# Constant in Ordinary Least Squares

Tags: regression, estimation, least-squares

Suppose, I estimate the model

$y_i = \beta_0 \,\mathrm{cons}_i$

with simple OLS, where $\mathrm{cons}_i$ is a variable that takes the value $1$ for each $i$ (classical constant). Why is the estimate $\widehat{\beta}_0$ the sample average of $y_i$?

Comment: No, I am curious.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the regression model is

$$ y_i = \beta_0 \,\mathrm{cons}_i + \varepsilon_i = \beta_0 + \varepsilon_i $$

writing it differently,

$$ E(Y) = E(\beta_0 + \varepsilon_i) = \underbrace{\beta_0 + E(\varepsilon_i) }_{\text{since } \beta_0 \text{ is constant}} = \underbrace{\beta_0 + 0}_{\text{since } E(\varepsilon_i) = 0} $$

so $E(Y) = \beta_0 = \bar Y$ (see [Why is expectation the same as the arithmetic mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30365/why-is-expectation-the-same-as-the-arithmetic-mean), and [Why do residuals in linear regression always sum to zero when an intercept is included?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189584/why-do-residuals-in-linear-regression-always-sum-to-zero-when-an-intercept-is-in) and [Why the sum of residuals equals 0 when we do a sample regression by OLS?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494181/why-the-sum-of-residuals-equals-0-when-we-do-a-sample-regression-by-ols)).

Saying it differently, we are looking for some $\beta_0$ value that minimizes squared errors (since OLS minimizes squared errors), and the value that minimizes squared error [is arithmetic mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/163413/35989) (see [Intuition on why the average minimizes the euclidean distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696622/intuition-on-why-the-average-minimizes-the-euclidean-distance)).