# Formula for expected value of continuous random variable without using density

Tags: expected-value, notation

I'm looking for some correct notation. Consider the random variable $V$ with support $\mathcal{V}$ and probability distribution $P_V$. Consider a function $u:\mathcal{V}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be finite and suppose I want to  compute the expected value of $u(V)$. This is

$$
\sum_{v\in \mathcal{V}} u(v)\times  P_{V}(v)
$$

Suppose now instead that $P_V$ is continuous. What is the correct notation to indicate the formula of the expected value of $u(V)$ without passing through the definition of density? I though about using
$$
\int_{\mathcal{V}} u(v)\text{ } dP_{V}(v)
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: There is one symbol without any explanation/definition in your writing.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is corrected now.

Comment: If you search for the ["law of the unconscious statistician"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) [on this forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1500751/14893) you will find many answers.

Comment: As suggested by @Xi'an, are you looking for an abstract expression as in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411201 $$E[V] = \int_\Omega V(\omega)\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega)$$ ($\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure, not a density), or do you seek an alternative way to compute the expectation that is not based on the density (there are many)?

Comment: Without using $\Omega$, is something like $\int_{\mathcal{V}}u(v) P(dv)$ admissible? I don't want to use $\Omega$ if possible.